# Mimetype mess after calibre installation. How can I fix it?

Tags: nautilus, file-format, mime-type, calibre

I always get `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream` when running "mimetype" on all file types.

The command "file --mime-type" seems to identify correctly the different file types. For instance, if I run it on a PDF file, I get

> `filename.pdf: application/pdf`

But if I try to run "mimetype" on the same PDF file, I get

> `filename.pdf: text/plain`

Similarly, if I run "file --mime-type" on a mp3 file, I get

> `filename.mp3: audio/mpeg`

But if I try to run "mimetype" on the same mp3 file, I get

> `filename.mp3: application/octet-stream`

As a consequence, I cannot open some files with the suitable application. For example. I cannot open a PDF file with evince. And I cannot set the "Open with" option of Nautilus to open each file-format with the suitable application.

I have tried to run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` but it does not fix the problem.

I have noticed that, if I run "mimetype" as the first user, I get this message

> `WARNING: You don't seem to have a mime-info database. The shared-mime-info package is available from http://freedesktop.org/`

However the shared-mime-info package seems to be correctly installed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `shared-mime-info`? You can do so with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall shared-mime-info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved reinstalling the `shared-mime-info` package, as suggested by  [Glutanimate](https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/glutanimate), with

> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall shared-mime-info`

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually fix this by editing the file:

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Remove all references to `calibre-ebook-edit.desktop;`, `calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop;`, and `calibre-gui.desktop;`.

The change will be instant, so you can test if the removed references resolved the default association.

This is not Ubuntu specific, should work on all distributions.