# 14.04 MIME type "png"

Tags: 14.04, mime-type, png

Error message clicking on nnn.png images (and no image display):

```
No default application found for the MIME type image/x-apple-ios-png.
Open the "File types and programs" page in the Control Center to add one.
```

This should work "out of the box" in 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Which environment?

Comment: Where (in which program, or give a screenshot) did you click on that image? That sould work indeed. The MIME type "image/x-apple-ios-png" is wrong - but why? It should be "image/png". Did you install anything apple related?

Comment: I experience the very same problem. I am confident I haven't installed anything from Apple, but LibreOffice 4.3 and VLC from PPA, as well as other software which does not offer the same functionality as EOG. On the other hand, I can't find de "Control Center" or any program with "File types and programs" page. What I am missing?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling `[shared-mime-info]`(http://askubuntu.com/q/486404/58950), to no avail.

Comment: Can you share the image...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean opening `*.png` files, mime type `x-apple-ios-png` with gnome commander.

The answer is there: http://gcmd.github.io/doc.html. Create three files in `~/.local/share/applications` directory:

**mimeapps.list**

```
[Default Applications]  
image/x-apple-ios-png=eog-usercreated.desktop
```

**eog-usercreated.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=eog  
MimeType=image/x-apple-ios-png;  
Exec='/usr/bin/eog'  
Type=Application  
Terminal=false  
NoDisplay=true
```

**mimeinfo.cache**

```
[MIME Cache]  
image/x-apple-ios-png=eog-usercreated.desktop
```

It works under Ubuntu 14.04.1, Gnome Commander 1.2.8.17

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
It really helped me.
And I wrote this code to be able to crop images:

**eog-usercreated.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=shotwell  
MimeType=image/x-apple-ios-png;  
Exec='/usr/bin/shotwell'  
Type=Application  
Terminal=false  
NoDisplay=true
```

Comment: Could you point out in an edit, how this is this relevant to the question asked ?